# How to indicate that a bootstrap responsive table is scrollable on iOS?

Tags: html, css, ios, bootstrap-4, safari

Using bootstrap 4 responsive table for example:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

The table does not appear scrollable on iOS until you try to scroll it, because the scrollbars are not showing, also Apple has removed the option to style the scrollbars to make them appear without any user interaction.

So if the table content is not visibly incomplete, for example half of a button showing on the right most table cell, the user will not know that there are possibly more columns that they are not seeing.

How do I indicate that the table is scrollable?

Comment: Possibility an idea to add a transparent CSS  down arrow at the bottom of the view-port  ( position: fixed; bottom: 0; ) . Have you looked at the Apple  documentation in regards to their user interface decision

Answer (score -1):

if you want to show horizontal scrollbar use `overflow-x: scroll;` and if you want to show vertical scroll bar use `overflow-y: scroll;` on `table`.

Let me know if this does not work